# Click on LiveTile doesn't show/run my app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-tile

In a background agent I create (or update) one of application live tiles and this works as expected.
Problem is that when I click this live tile screen flickers but my app is not "restarted" nor "shown".
What's wrong?
I attach small part of the code, but ask for more is you need.

**MAIN PAGE**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Runs background agent: code is simplified
        StartAgent();
    }
}
```

**BACKGROUND AGENT**

```
public class TileAgent : ScheduledTaskAgent
{
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            Vars.UpdateTiles();
        });

        NotifyComplete();
    }
}
```

**STATIC CLASS**

```
public class Vars
{
    private static Uri uri = new Uri(
        "/MainPage.xaml?tile",
        UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    private static RadExtendedTileData ExtendedData
    {
        get
        {
            return new RadExtendedTileData()
            {
                VisualElement = frontTile,
                BackVisualElement = backTile,                    
            };
        }
    }

    public static void UpdateTiles()
    {
        // I perform some task here

        // Then I create/update live tile
        Telerik.Windows.Controls.LiveTileHelper.CreateOrUpdateTile(
            ExtendedData, uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using standard tile info instead of Telerik?

Comment: I don't see where you start your application.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot: no, I need Telerik because it lets me create custom tiles.

Comment: @Ramhound: my app is started on MainPage (according to manifest). When I manually run the app it works well; problem occurs when I click on live tile: screen flickers and app is not restarted nor brought to front even if live tile uri seems (to me) correct.

Comment: try `/MainPage.xaml?tile=true` instead of `/MainPage.xaml?tile`

Comment: and move `NotifyComplete()` into the dispatcher call. otherwise it will be called before the operation has been completed...

Comment: @RicoSuter: you're correct in everything. Post your comment as answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot!! Can you explain why changing uri with `tile=true` makes it work?

Comment: Asking b/c I'm not sure, is the BeginInvoke necessary?  I use the LiveTileHelper form an agent and don't call BeginInvoke.

Comment: @DerekBeattie: I need because I'm changing visual elements and I get a cross-thread violation.

Comment: is ?tile an invalid Uri?

Comment: @DerekBeattie: I don't know, but probably yes...

Comment: @Marco I understand but does the LiveTileHelper already do that, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `/MainPage.xaml?tile=true` instead of `/MainPage.xaml?tile`...

And move `NotifyComplete()` into the dispatcher call. Otherwise it will be called before the operation has been completed...